# No input file specified nginx nginx/1.10.3

Tags: php, nginx

I have simple php file in /var/www/html/test directory. The php file has simple echo statement only. I tried to access the file like http://exampe.com/test/test.php. It shows **No input file specified**. If it was in /var/www/html/ it was working fine. Can anyone try to help me?

Comment: What server are you using? This could be due to nginx configuration (root folder). There is more elaborate explanation here: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,231954,232017